# quitar guiones en primera fila de csv generado por sql

Tags: sql, csv

Estoy creando un csv generado por un query y enviandolo via email pero en la primera fila me salen estos guiones.

```
------------------


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients='prueba@prueba.com',
    @subject='CSV Extract', 
    @profile_name = @profile,
    @body= 'See attachment',
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @query =@qry,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'CSV_file.csv',
    @query_result_separator = ',',
    @query_result_width = 32767,
    @exclude_query_output = 1,
    @query_result_header =1,
    @query_result_no_padding = 1
```

Existe una forma de eliminar la primera fila o los guiones?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe forma de eliminar los guiones si incluyes el encabezado, pero si se puede eliminar el encabezado completamente, lo cual quita los títulos de las columnas y la línea con guiones.

El procedimiento [`sp_send_dbmail`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql) acepta el parámetro `@query_result_header`, un `bit` que tiene por defecto `1`, pero se puede colocar en `0` (tu actualmente lo estás incluyendo con valor `1`):

```
XEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients='prueba@prueba.com',
    @subject='CSV Extract', 
    @query_result_header=0,
    bla,
    bla, 
    bla
```